# PowerShell Hashmap typecasting

Tags: powershell, hashmap

I want to create a hashmap in which key will be string and value will be integer. I tried this:

```
$map=@{}
$map.add("first",1)
$map.add("sec",r)
```

I have created one function that will accept string and integer:

```
function fun([string]$name,[int]$val)
{
..............
}
```

And i am trying to call this function like:

```
$map.keys | % { fun -name $_ -value $map.Item($_)}
```

Please suggest me, how can i call this function?

Comment: What is your problem? Do you got any error message? Your code look valid to me, except you declare function `f` but call `fun` and you declare parameter `$val` but use `-value`.

Comment: yes " cannot convert the System.objects[] value of the type System.objects[] to type System.int32"

Comment: Could you provide complete code sample demonstrating error?

Comment: You have an `r` string instead of an integer in your second `$map.add()`.

Comment: @Kev Even worse, it's not even quoted so it isn't a string, but an expression that will fail. :)

Comment: @FrodeF. indeed....I meant to say "character" instead of string, but by then the edit window had expire, but figured OP would get the jist.

Answer (score 2):

1. "sec" has a value of an unquoted `r`, which is an expression that will fail when added and even if it was quoted as a string it would have failed in `fun` since it's not an `int`.
2. You function declares the parameter `$val`, but you use `-value` when you call it, this would make the output return `0` where `$value` is used and not the value from the hashtable.

Fixed sample:

```
$map=@{}
$map.add("first",1)
$map.add("sec",2)

function fun([string]$name,[int]$val)
{
    "$name is $val"
}

$map.keys | % { fun -name $_ -val $map.Item($_)}
sec is 2
first is 1
```